# Why is col-md-X not in this list of classes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 and went to style my website as follows

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-12 col-md-6'>
    1
   </div>
  <div class='col-12 col-md-6'>
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

So that on medium+ screens, it is two columns, while on smaller screens it is one column. However, it is appearing as one column on all sized screens.

The column system is definitely working -- when I switch it to `col-sm-6` it works fine. I can't figure out why `col-md-6` isn't being registered, and when I looked at the css loaded classes, there didn't seem to be any `md` loaded (not formatted as code block to disable x-scroll):

.col, .col-1, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-auto, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-auto, .col-md, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-auto, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-auto, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-auto

```
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

What's different about `col-md-x` sizes that it isn't appearing here / not working for my column layout?

Comment: How are you importing bootstrap?

Comment: Using bootstrap.min.css that I have in my css/ folder. v4.0.0

Comment: Where did you download it? Latest is v4.3.1 - just downloaded it and confirmed `col-md-*` classes exist

Comment: Try `<div class='col-lg-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12'>`

Comment: Just updated to v4.3.1 -- still seeing col-, col-sm, col-lg, col-xl... but no col-md!

Comment: Working on codepen https://codepen.io/asdf8b432y9vhs9vt8/pen/yLBvMVW -- must be something on my system then

Comment: It works when I use the CDN, but breaks when I copy and paste the code into a file and read it from there. No idea why.